# phantom JS configuration when used with InternJS

Tags: phantomjs, intern

I want to use phantomJS with Intern for functional testing.

- I Installed phantomJS and ran the command "phantomjs --webdriver 4444", it ran successfully.
- Then tried to run intern-runner with the command "intern-runner config=tests/intern" **-file tests/intern is shown at the end of the post-**.

but i keep getting the error

```
intern-runner config=tests/intern  
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000  
Tunnel started  
Suite phantomjs on any platform FAILED  
UnknownError: [POST http: //localhost:4444/wd/hub/session / {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"phantomjs","name":"tests/intern","idle-timeout":60}}] An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
```

on intern.

and the error

```
[ERROR - 2015-10-14T10:14:35.611Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"message":"{
\"headers\":{\"Connection\":\"close\",\"Host\":\"localhost:4444\",\"accept\":\"a
pplication/json,text/plain;q=0.9\",\"content-length\":\"91\",\"content-type\":\"
application/json;charset=UTF-8\",\"user-agent\":\"dojo/2.0.0-dev Node.js/4.1.2\"
},\"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"url\":\"/session\",\"urlParsed\"
:{\"anchor\":\"\",\"query\":\"\",\"file\":\"session\",\"directory\":\"/\",\"path
\":\"/session\",\"relative\":\"/session\",\"port\":\"\",\"host\":\"\",\"password
\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"userInfo\":\"\",\"authority\":\"\",\"protocol\":\"\",\"s
ource\":\"/session\",\"queryKey\":{},\"chunks\":[\"session\"]}}","name":"Missing
 Command Parameter","line":85,"sourceId":65775352,"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/req
uest_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js","stack":"Missing Command Param
eter: {\"headers\":{\"Connection\":\"close\",\"Host\":\"localhost:4444\",\"accep
t\":\"application/json,text/plain;q=0.9\",\"content-length\":\"91\",\"content-ty
pe\":\"application/json;charset=UTF-8\",\"user-agent\":\"dojo/2.0.0-dev Node.js/
4.1.2\"},\"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"url\":\"/session\",\"urlP
arsed\":{\"anchor\":\"\",\"query\":\"\",\"file\":\"session\",\"directory\":\"/\"
,\"path\":\"/session\",\"relative\":\"/session\",\"port\":\"\",\"host\":\"\",\"p
assword\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"userInfo\":\"\",\"authority\":\"\",\"protocol\":\
"\",\"source\":\"/session\",\"queryKey\":{},\"chunks\":[\"session\"]}}\n    at :
/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js:85\n    at :/gh
ostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js:44\n    at :/ghost   
driver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js:70","stackArray":[{"sourceURL"
:":/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js","line":85},
{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/request_handlers/session_manager_request_handler.js"
,"line":44},{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.
js","line":70}]}
```

on phantomjs **- this error appears after running the intern-runner-**.

does anyone know what the problem is?.

p.s. I'm using phantomJS v.1.9.8

---

```
tests/intern :  

define({
proxyPort: 9000,
proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
environments: [
    { browserName: 'phantomjs' }
],
maxConcurrency: 3,
useSauceConnect: false,
loaders: {
  'host-browser': 'node_modules/requirejs/require.js'
},
tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/modetest' ],

});
```

Comment: "Missing Command Parameter" looks like a bug in intern or an incompatible Ghostdriver version which is included in PhantomJS. What PhantomJS version are you using? This is probably better suited as a bug report on the intern project.

Comment: The phantomJS version is 1.9.8 , i edited the question to contain this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 1 is ancient (it uses a version of WebKit from 2012) and not supported. You must use PhantomJS 2+ with Intern.

Comment: Thank you ,i tried using phantomJS2, this time intern started normally but it then returned `CancelError: Timeout reached on phantomjs` , and phantomJS returned a different error`[ERROR - 2015-10-15T07:29:36.643Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"name":"Inva lid Command Method" ...... :262 in error`, any idea what that means ?

Comment: any update on this? @hassan ...I am getting the same issue with Intern 3 and Phantom 2.

Comment: No, this task was frozen, and i switched to another task. but this question is basically dead. You should probably start another question